# Sending test ether on Testrpc

Tags: solidity, truffle, testrpc, testing

I'm using Truffle Version 2.1 and I'm trying to send test ether to my contract using Testrpc. 
I run `testrpc -u 0 -u 1`

 
And the accounts shows a balance of 99351632199997083360 wei
I'm trying to send Ether to a function that contains the payable modifier and returns true (no inner code), and it is returning with a VM jump.

```
    function fund() payable returns (bool) {

    return true; 
}
```

And this is the truffle javascript calling the function

```
var projectBeingFunded = Project.at(projectToFund);
return projectBeingFunded.fund({from: account, amount:amountToGive}); 
}).then(function(txHash) { 
    waitForTransaction(); 
    return web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(txHash); 
  }).then(function(receipt) { 
        console.log("transaction receipt");
        console.log(receipt.valueOf());
        setStatus("Project successfully funded");
      }).catch(function(e) { 
        console.log(e);
        setStatus("Project funding didn't work");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're submitting an argument called amount, not a payment in Ether.

```
return projectBeingFunded.fund({from: account, amount:amountToGive});
```

That would almost be appropriate if the contract function read:

```
function fund(uint amount) returns(bool) {}
```

Would actually be:

```
return projectBeingFunded.fund(amountToGive, {from: account});
```

But it actually says no arguments are expected, and ETH *is* expected:

```
function fund() payable returns (bool) { ...
```

The unexpected argument is a JUMP. So, try this:

```
return projectBeingFunded.fund({from: account, value: amountToGive});
```

Where amountToGive is a uint in Wei and the sender has that much money, as I assume is the case.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Upon a closer look, I realized there is indeed a problem with the original syntax causing the JUMP but I didn't describe it very well. Corrected to avoid misleading you and others.

Comment: what if I want to call this function `function fund() payable returns (bool)` from inside another contract in solidity?